# Prevent PHPStorm IDE From Corrupting Images

Tags: phpstorm

Ever since I switched from Eclipse PDT to PHPStorm, I've been having problems on my site where images won't display correctly, especially the little icons in TinyMCE. My favicon also seems to be corrupted.

I'm sure the problem is that PHPStorm is doing a newline character substitution and not respecting my image files as Binary files. When I compare an image from the server with what I have stores locally, I see that it's doing newline substitution.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Here's the example of what one should do in Eclipse. I think I'm looking for something similar in PHPStorm.

[image: Example in Eclipse]

Comment: Your question belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: @alexn I'm not sure it does - I think it falls into the "software tools commonly used by programmers" category

Comment: More useful than stop Eclipse/PhpStorm from replacing the line endings in text files is to flag the images as binaries

Comment: Thanks @KingCrunch. How does one go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work!

Just before checking your project out, you need to check "change keyword substitution to" and choose "binary".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Settings
IDE Settings
File Types
```

Upper half of the dialog select `Image Files`. Below click on `Add` and type `*.ico`, or whetever the file extension of your files is.

Should do it

Comment: Hmmm... all the file extensions I need are already there [except for *.ico which I just added]. Still having the same problem.